# How can I Delete an iOS device on my iOS Device list?

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-developer-program

I got a little  problem with Apple and my iPhone 5. The problem is that, on my developer account on Apple, I've two devices with the same UDID (yes the same!) but one is called iPhone5 and it's enable... The other one is Called iOS Dev Device and it's disable.

The weird part is that on xCode it notices me that I've my iPhone disable and so I can't use it to test my apps (maybe because it take the references of the one called "iOS Dev Device") and if I try to enable it via Web Apple notices me that I've already a device with that UDID enable because I've another Device with the same UDID, called iPhone5, Enable!

Is there any solution for this situation?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: I should think you should be able to head to the "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" section of your Apple Developer account and delete your current development provisioning profile. Then delete whichever device you want to remove from your devices list, then create a new provisioning profile. Xcode should automatically catch up with the changes when you refresh its profiles view in the Organizer.

Comment: Just to add to that: is there something stopping you simply deleting devices from your device list on Apple Dev site?

Comment: @davidf2281 maybe you have already got the answer, but you can only delete devices once per year, when you renew your developer subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think it is possible to delete a `UDID` from a profile till profiles renewal date, so once you add the device `UDID` it will stay there until expiration date of your profile.

Try disabling both devices on the Web, in your mac connect the device and go to Organizer click your device delete provisioning profiles in your device, right click the device and try to add it again it must give an error saying that device is already added to your profile, thats fine, try to run the app again on device with xcode again. This is just an idea hopefully that works, otherwise just try to enable the the device that really matches with the name on profile.

Comment: I'm going to try it now. I report you what will happen